# Spring CRUDRepository save nested Json Column in Postgres/Hibernate/Jackson

Tags: json, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to save an entity in a Postgres DB, using Spring/Hibernate/Jackson.

Entity JSON:

```
{"Block": {"hash":"abc123", "tx":[{"hash":"xyz321", "number":5}, {"hash":"xyz321", "number":5}]}}
```

I want the Transaction entity in Java to have a String field to represent the hash, and a JSON object/string representing the list of inputs (custom entity); i.e. the list of transactions would be: (stored as json in the database)

```
"tx":[{"hash":"xyz321", "number":5}, {"hash":"xyz321", "number":5}]
```

My Transaction entity:

```
public class Transaction implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty("hash")
    @Column(name = "hash", unique = true)
    private String hash;

    @JsonProperty("vin")
    @Column(name = "vin", nullable = false)
    @Type(type = "TxVinUserType")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = vinDeserialiser.class)
    public List<TxVin> txVin;
}
```

My custom Hibernate UserType:

```
public class TxVinUserType implements UserType {

@Override
public int[] sqlTypes() {
    return new int[] { Types.JAVA_OBJECT };
}

@Override
public Class<TxVin> returnedClass() {
    return TxVin.class;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
    return ObjectUtils.nullSafeEquals(x, y);
}

@Override
public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
    if (x == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    return x.hashCode();
}

@Override
public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, SessionImplementor session, Object owner)
        throws HibernateException, SQLException {

    PGobject o = (PGobject) rs.getObject(names[0]);
    if (o.getValue() != null) {
        try {
            return new ObjectMapper().readValue(o.getValue(), TxVin.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return new TxVin();

}

@Override
public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session)
        throws HibernateException, SQLException {

    if (value == null) {
        st.setNull(index, Types.OTHER);
    } else {
        String s;
        try {
            s = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(value);
            st.setObject(index, s, Types.OTHER);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

@Override
public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
    if (value == null) {
        return null;
    }

    if (!(value instanceof TxVin)) {
        return null;
    }

    return (TxVin) value;
}

@Override
public boolean isMutable() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
    Object copy = deepCopy(value);

    if (copy instanceof Serializable) {
        return (Serializable) copy;
    }

    throw new SerializationException(
            String.format("Cannot serialize '%s', %s is not Serializable.", value, value.getClass()), null);
}

@Override
public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
    return deepCopy(cached);
}

@Override
public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
    return deepCopy(original);
}

}
```

I'm using Spring Data's CrudRepository. When I try to save a transaction (which has a valid txVin list) I get this error:

```
"org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "vin" violates not-null constraint"
```

So my question is, why is Spring generating null values when trying to use CrudRepository.save()?

Comment: So where is the problem? JPA persists a java object to PostgreSQL and it says there is a null field. So where do you get the object from? in which case JPA is not the problem, and your JSON usage is. Hence JPA is irrelevant to the problem and can be untagged

Comment: Yes, it says there is a null field, however when I look at the object right before it's saved, it has those fields; they shouldn't be null. The JSON is being deserialised correctly.

Comment: it is your `vinDeserialiser` generating the null value for the column

Comment: @Paizo It's not. The List<TxVin> is not empty.

Comment: Ok but then how can your custom type in a list fit in a column? Don't you have to create a relation to a  `WhateverEntity` containing your custom type? Also why a custom type?

Comment: Custom type because apparently Hibernate doesn't play well with json, and requires you to write a custom type for it. Could you explain the other question a bit more?